Best Practices for Restricting Domain Administrator Access in Active Directory
I’m seeking insights on the best practices for securing Domain and Active Directory environments, specifically regarding limiting of Domain Administrator access privileges. The goal is to ensure that individuals with Domain Admin account privileges  have limited access or denied modification to the credentials of senior management (can be Domain Administrator account or domain account) within an organization.(Since Domain Authentication is also used to access some of the internal confidential applications)
I’m interested in learning about the various solutions that can be implemented, whether they are technological, strategic or based on an understanding between the IT department and upper management.
In my research I have found that:
·        Most commonly an Identity and Access Management solution (IAM) inclusive of both Privileged Access Management (PAM) and Privileged Identity Management (PIM) solutions are generally deployed.
·        Other solutions include Tiering Approach and then limiting access based on tiers.
·        Another cost effective but not very dynamic approach was break-glass domain admin account, no day to day activities are done by Domain Admin Accounts, all the daily/ regular tasks can be delegated initially and then the domain admin account can be made break-glass, i.e. change password and new password known to no one but only person incharge, and can be given to the authorized person whenever required (critical situations).
Please feel free to add any other methods, which I may not considered.
So it boils down to what are the standard methods companies typically take to protect the sensitive accounts of their leadership team from being accessed by Domain Administrators? How do they balance the need for security with the necessary access rights for IT operations?
Any shared experiences, insights, or recommended resources would be greatly appreciated.

That isn't what a break glass account is. It is for the builtin Administrator account. It doesn't apply in any way to the 100 other equivalent accounts.

Any admin worth their salt could do more damage without needing access to executive's password.   If you're super concerned about this - then stream logs to a 3rd party XDR for analysis and have them alert appropriate people on executive password resets.  I look at this as concern as bordering on the trivial.  There is so much ACTUAL risk out there...whatever.  Tiering accounts is a good thing -- but it comes down to, if you can't trust a person with "Domain Admin", they shouldn't be "Domain Admin"

Your main mitigations are:

Use the tiered approach that Microsoft discusses in their Securing Active Directory guide https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/plan/security-best-practices/best-practices-for-securing-active-directory

It may not be possible to implement the full guidance per Microsoft, but you should definitely delegate permissions for the typical management tasks to members of designated role groups. Do not create "all in one" role groups that basically just replicate DA. Think about staff who manage servers, accounts, databases, workstations - these are different roles, even if some staff might do multiple tasks. Leave only Administrator as a member of Domain Admins. Selected accounts should be only granted temporary membership to Domain Admins for specific tasks and receive approval to do so. Or, I've seen DA-specific accounts that are assigned to very few specific individuals which are left in a disabled state and can only be re-enabled by members of a specific group.

If you don't have a PAM/PIM solution, members of those role groups should be specific admin accounts that are used only on designated computers in a "management" network segment or similar.

The most important is to implement AUDITING, preferably using a well-established SIEM solution, and especially to monitor changes to the built-in privileged groups plus any other role groups you create for admin purposes. This should be alongside a good change control process so that you know WHY elevated perms may be needed. Also, auditing should be enabled at the server, file system and application level per vendor best practices. AD-specific guidance is at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/plan/security-best-practices/audit-policy-recommendations

Follow any government or industry standards or recommendations for cybersecurity practices - for example, the ACSC in Australia, NCSC in the UK, NIST in the US.


Also, it should not be possible for domain admins to routinely get access to databases, mailboxes and so on. It may be possible for DAs to assign themselves delegations to these things, but if you have any "default" permissions granting DAs or other administrators access to user data, these should be reviewed.
An organisation may not be able to prevent a malicious admin from getting into things they shouldn't, but implementing extra security layers and AUDITING and related controls are ways of reducing the likelihood.
And the above only scratches the surface. I would highly recommend the organisation appoint a CISO and/or hire security consultants with expertise in these technologies if you're starting from nothing, effectively.
